# How to format a top10 counter function

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

I have a list of strings and want to count the number of times each string is mentioned in the list and then format them nicely.

I've managed to get the list to print out formatted how I want it using this code:

```py
def top10(items):
    return Counter(items).most_common(10)

for key, val in top10(items):
    print(key, '=', val)
```

But am now having trouble embedding it into the top10 function.

I've tried a few things, and this was the only one that printed any results:

```py
def top10(items):
    for key, val in Counter(items).most_common(10):
        return(key, '=', val)
print(top10(items))
```

It only prints the most common string, and formatted in the wrong way, so literally like this: (key, "=", val).

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please explain more about your expected ouput

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. I want it to print the format that i outlined in the first code. So it will print the word on the right, this is 'key', then =, then the number of times it occurs in the list, this is 'value.' Hope this helps, sorry for the vagueness

Comment: your first code works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not return the value: instead, use it in your code lines that print. And do the printing in the function. Here is one way:

```
from collections import Counter

def top10(items):
    for key, val in Counter(items).most_common(10):
        print(key, '=', val)

top10([1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,5,6,1,7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13])
```

The printout from that is

```
1 = 5
5 = 2
2 = 1
3 = 1
4 = 1
6 = 1
7 = 1
8 = 1
9 = 1
10 = 1
```

Comment: that worked well, thank you. it's now also printed None as the final element in the table. Is this because there's an empty value in my list? When I used the first code, this didn't happen

Comment: @adam22: I cannot say unless you show a complete code snippet that shows the problem. I can only guess otherwise. But probably you already have a `None` in your `items` variable.

Comment: made a silly mistake, it was because i used print(top10(items), rahter than just calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

may be what you intended to do is

```py
def top10(items):
    for key, val in top10(items):
        print(key, '=', val)

    return Counter(items).most_common(10)

top10(items)
```

But why do you want to print values in same function that is meant to return top10 items. This way your function always print the counter when you call it. You need to aim to make you function as small as possible and do only one thing in it. So I suggest you following which is near to your last solution

```py
def print_top(items):
    for key, val in Counter(items).most_common(10):
        return(key, '=', val)

print_top(top10(items)):
```